# Angular 2/4: Loading all Text from separate file for easier Modifying, Testing & Internationalisation

Tags: html, string, angular, text

wondering how I'd go about saving the various texts I want to use for my angular application in a separate file and only making calls to this text file to popukate the page.

e.g, in a login page, I'd want to save the String "Login" in a separate file instead of just putting it in the html. Makes it easier to switch to "Anmeldung" if I ever have to include German functionality for example
That should aid a ton when making changes, adding another language and just makes the application much more manageable.

Cheers

Comment: I use @ngx-translate for this. http://www.ngx-translate.com/

Comment: This is definitely a possibility. For some reason, only found ng translate for AngularJS and thought there wasn't any for ng2 even after a cursory google search. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a whole section in documentation for it. A bit too broad question to give short answer.

ref: https://angular.io/guide/i18n